# How do I display results of a form submission based on the selection using magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, popup

Ok so I have form that has 3 radio buttons and a select drop down menu and a submit button. I have the HTML in place, but I am having trouble using magnific pop up to open the results based on what choices are selected. Here is the HTML and JQuery I'm using:

```
           <form class="dnt-tool" action="#popup" name="dnt" id="dnt" method="POST">
               <div class="dnt-overlay">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male"><label for="male">Male</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female"><label for="female">Female</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="all" checked><label for="all">All</label>
                    <select>
                        <option>Select a Category</option>
                        <option>Catgeory 1</option>
                        <option>Catgeory 2</option>
                        <option>Category 3</option>
                    </select>
               </div><!-- end of dnt-overlay -->
               <div class="dnt-btn">
                   <button type="submit" id="submit">Show Names</button>
               </div><!-- end of dnt btn -->
         </form>
```

This is the JQuery:

```
              $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#dnt').submit(function(){
                      $.ajax({
                          data: $(this).serialize, //get the form data 
                          type: $(this).attr('method'),
                          url: $(this).attr('action'), //the file or div to call
                          success: function(response){
                              $('#submit').magnificPopup({
                                   type: 'inline',
                                   modal: true
                              });
                         }
                    });//ajax
              });//submit function

            });//JQuery
```

Any ideas on what's missing? Oh and here's the link to magnific popup if you're not familiar with it: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: what is magnific popup? if there is no tag for it you should at least add a link to the library so we know what you're talking about

Comment: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

Comment: Have you tried inserting a console.log() in your success function to verify that it's being hit?  I suspect the problem may be your AJAX call, and not your popup.

Comment: @devlincarnate I just tried it nothing at all

Comment: This is really strange how you want to achieve this. Why are you using an Ajax when you are not 'sending' data anywhere. You can simply pickup the answers with jQ and then process it.
BTW: What are you trying to achieve? When a form is submitted open a certain modal?

Comment: @Maverick  I want a different modal to popup based on what radio button was selected, after the form is submitted.

Comment: @MikeL5799 I don't see a point of using Ajax here, you can use jQ to check the values

Comment: I will post and answer now

Comment: Ok thanks @Maverick as usual, I overthought this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments I don't see a point of using Ajax here, because you can achieve asynchronous JS here and there no 'data processing'.

### Best solution:

I think we can agree the solutions above are not that great, because the code is not 'dynamic' and will get pretty long.

So here is a perfect solution:

In html you create a `div` with `id` in this way:
`radioID_modal`.

For your example:

```
<div id="male_modal" class="custom-modal mfp-hide">
  Custom modal for male
</div>

<div id="female_modal" class="custom-modal mfp-hide">
  Custom modal for female
</div>

<div id="all_modal" class="custom-modal mfp-hide">
  Custom modal for female
</div>
```

Here is a much simpler JS:

```
$('#dnt').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // We don't need to send the form, because it all local

  // We get the ID of the checked radio button
  var checkedRadio = $('[name="gender"]:checked').attr('id');

  $.magnificPopup.open({ // Call mfp on jQ object
      items: {
        src: '#' + checkedRadio + '_modal',
        type: 'inline'
      }
        });
});
```

We get the `id` from the radio button and open a modal with id `# ID _modal`. And this is all the JS you will need, no ifs nor multiple magnificPopup declarations.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4verick/Ly57yo3z/)

## Other solutions

### Premade modals

You can make premade modals and just call them when needed.

```
<div id="option1" class="custom-modal mfp-hide">
  Custom modal for male
</div>
```

Now when form is submitted we check the data. There are a lot of ways of doing this.

```
$('#dnt').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // We don't need to send the form, because it all local
  if($('#male').is(':checked')) { // Check if male is checked
        $.magnificPopup.open({ // Call mfp on jQ object
      items: {
        src: '#option1',
        type: 'inline'
      }
        });
  }
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4verick/84g1b9Lw/1/)

### Dynamic modals

You can dynamically construct the modals, this is usefully if little data is changed.

You just need to replace the `src` with the element:

```
$('#dnt').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // We don't need to send the form, because it all local
  if($('#male').is(':checked')) { // Check if male is checked
        $.magnificPopup.open({ // Call mfp on jQ object
      items: {
        src: $('<div>Dynamically created element</div>'), // Create it now
        type: 'inline'
      }
        });
  }
});
```

Comment: Glad that I could help.